# mod_pagespeed forgets optimizations after a while

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-pagespeed

I've setup mod_pagespeed and it seems to work fine, but only when I reload a page. Minutes later the optimization is gone.

Here's a static site where full optimization is only done when you reload the page:
[twitterbogen.dk](http://twitterbogen.dk/)

On the first load the CSS files have no .pagespeed. in them. If you reload they do.
Any idea why?

Here's my [Apache Server Information](https://gist.github.com/2950985).

And here's my mod_pagespeed configuration:

```
ModPagespeed on
AddOutputFilterByType MOD_PAGESPEED_OUTPUT_FILTER text/html
ModPagespeedFileCachePath            "/var/www/mod_pagespeed/cache/"
ModPagespeedGeneratedFilePrefix      "/var/www/mod_pagespeed/files/"
ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_javascript,rewrite_css
ModPagespeedEnableFilters collapse_whitespace,elide_attributes
ModPagespeedEnableFilters extend_cache,combine_css,move_css_above_scripts,move_css_to_head,inline_css,inline_import_to_link,flatten_css_imports,inline_javascript,outline_javascript,rewrite_style_attributes,rewrite_images,sprite_images
ModPagespeedAvoidRenamingIntrospectiveJavascript on
ModPagespeedMessageBufferSize 100000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a great answer:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mod-pagespeed-discuss/m4TupdDEUp0/fijGgKDOlV8J